# alipay intergration page not found

Tags: integration, alipay

Anyone having expierience with the integration of Alipay?

I tried the method on the following page:
https://globalprod.alipay.com/order/integrationGuide.htm

But after editing my hostfile I get an "Server not found" on the following URL:
https://excashier.alipay.net/standard/auth.htm?auth_order_id=exc_2986bbacc22f46a7bca423e396777f37&_cache_context_token=FSGDdsr6ZgMVHOn14Ym6akIeYBGUZma4

Anyone have an idea?

greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add in your hosts file

```
115.124.16.59 mapi.alipay.net excashier.alipay.net
```